# CakePHP Get translated data from the model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, translate

I am using cakephp 2.x to make one site multilingual and I am using the i18n extract and the TranslateBehavior Core Library.

The i18n works fine and the TranslateBehavior Core Library works fine when I try to save data. But when I want to read it I have to say to the controller the specific locale with:

```
$this->Home->locale = 'spa';
```

or

```
$this->Home->locale = 'eng';
```

Instead the core library makes it automatically by me. I have to specify all the times the locale? Or does exist something that do it automatically?

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe You can use constant DEFAULT_LANGUAGE

Comment: But I have to make it manually. I want that the web page makes it by itself :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed article about i18n on Cakephp 1.3, I hope your 2.x will also work on this say theory so you can have a try with that http://codeatomic.com/developing-cakephp-multilingual-website/